# Downgrade RPM Version on CentOS

Tags: centos, yum, rpm

I am trying to downgrade my version of `RPM` as a package itself rather then just downgrading an .rpm of some other package.

I am trying to create some .rpm files but the target machines have such an old version of `RPM` installed that it looks like my current .rpm supplied uses newer libraries.

```
[root@lonlx1071b11 tmp]# rpm -ivh agents-1.0-1.x86_64.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
    rpmlib(FileDigests) <= 4.6.0-1 is needed by agents-1.0-1.x86_64
    rpmlib(PayloadIsXz) <= 5.2-1 is needed by agents-1.0-1.x86_64
```

My current `RPM` version is:

```
root@localhost tmp]# rpm --version
RPM version 4.11.3
```

Target current `RPM` version is:

```
[root@lonlx1071b11 ~]# rpm --version
RPM version 4.4.2.3
```

When I try to `yum downgrade rpm-4.4.2.3-36.el5_11.x86_64.rpm`

I get dependency errors. Removing `RPM` and re-installing it doesn't work either as it says I try and remove `yum` and that's protected. So I assume `yum` is using `RPM`

If there is an obvious solution to this I apologise but I have not a fair bit of research and I can't really seem to find a solution.

I can post the dependency errors if required but they are fairly large. I have left them out for now to make the question easier to read.

Comment: I am extremely new to Linux so I might need some clarification on answers. Sorry!

Comment: FYI, `yum` uses `rpm` under the hood.  Why do you want to downgrade RPM, anyway?  That's not something a newbie to Linux should generally need or want to do.

Comment: Yeah I thought so. Because I need to build the .rpm files for an older machine and the error given when trying to install those .rpm file suggests that its the older version of RPM that is causing a problem.

Comment: I would bet it's the tool you're using to *build* the RPM.  `rpmbuild`, perhaps?  And I would bet that has options to build `rpm` files for older versions of the `rpm` installer.  Have you looked into that?

Comment: No I have not. Thanks! I will look into that. If I find something useful in the mean time I will take the question down.

Comment: If you find the answer yourself, you can self-answer your question; that's generally better than taking it down.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't simply clone the target as a VM and work inside that? Usually this is the fastest way to keep versions straight.

Comment: Possibly the requirements are false - can you edit the SPEC file to modify those dependencies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to http://rpm.org/max-rpm-snapshot/ch-rpm-b-command.html

I can use --rcfile  to use a different set of RPM defaults.

Unfortunately my access to the target is limited so I could not get the rcfile for this. I ended up just spinning up an early image of CentOS that uses the target rpm version and created the packages again.